# Would earning reports or other filings for a retail outlet include a breakdown of sales by category?

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, corporate-earnings

I am evaluating stock traded on NASDAQ for a retail establishment. I want to learn what portion of this establishments sales come from different departments. For example, I want to know if 20% of sales were from sporting goods and 50% was from housewares.

Is this type of information required to be reported on any particular filing or report?

Is this type of information commonly reported on any particular filing or report?

What other common forms or sources of information might have this data?

Comment: I don't know what level of detail is required but that kind of information is typically found in the quarterly/annual reports. Without knowing which company you're looking at, it's hard to give you more specific information. For example, Target shows the high-level breakdown on the [first page](https://corporate.target.com/_media/TargetCorp/annualreports/2016/pdfs/Target-2016-Annual-Report.pdf) (PDF)

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD I framed my question generally because I want to learn how to do this for any given retailer, not just the one I am currently looking at. Your comment does directly answer my question, I searched for "annual report TICKERSYMBOL" and found what I needed

Comment: @Freiheit Outside the financial statements, the regulations around what must be in a financial report are pretty lax. So there's no guarantee that every retailer will have such a breakdown in their annual report, but that is the most likely source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching for the company annual report was able to answer my question. This was as simple as "annual report TICKER_SYMBOL" in a search engine. The annual report then had the sales information by category and remarks on each categories performance, growth, and future for the company.